# Regex trouble: Why does this not match?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, regex-greedy

I need the an **always matching (!)** regex to extract data in Postgresql (with regexp_matches).

This is an example input:

```
#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb
```

And my regex:

```
/(?:showcatalog=([0-9]+))?/
```

I tried this with Perl:

```
perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper([ "#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb" =~ /(?:showcatalog=([0-9]+))?/ ]);'
```

And expected a `$VAR1 = [ 123 ]` but got a `$VAR1 = [ undef ]`. I don't understand, because '?' is greedy, and it's not behaving as such. What didn't I understand? I tried regex101.com which didn't help me. How to get the expected result?

Shouldn't it give preference to match the text, being greedy?

If there is nothing, to match, such as in

```
#link text=blurb"
```

I just want to get `$VAR1 = [ undef ]`

Comment: Can you provide some input data for your regex?

Comment: @JohnDoe: the input is "#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb". The expected output is "[ match ]" if it matches and "[ undef ]" if not.

Comment: So your real question is about `select regexp_matches('#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb', '(?:showcatalog=([0-9]+))?');` in postgresql, right ? I think all this perl stuff doesn't make the question clearer.

Comment: **Why** did you add this `?`? It means it also matches if the group is not here. Can you explain the real goal ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I want it to work in postgresql, yes. I expressed it in perl to show that it's not a postgresql-specific question rather then a regex-question. Ah well, perhaps i should remove the postgresql reference to avoid confusion...

Comment: There's no pure "regex-question". A regex question is always dependent of the tool or language.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I need the regex always to be matching. really, i do.

Comment: So why not `(?:showcatalog=([0-9]*))` ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I hoped the question is clear: Why does the supplied perl one liner doesn't output the expected value. What is my misunderstanding with the greediness of '?'

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Because I always need it tho match. really, really.

Comment: What result do you want when the input string is for exemple `"nothing"`? Please clarify your need.

Comment: What's the source text you're trying to parse here? It looks like it might be something structured, like XML or HTML. If so, a parser is probably better than a regex.

Comment: @Searle , can I rewrite your question? It seems that no one understands what you're asking

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I added another example. For "nothing" the expected output would be "[ undef ]"

Comment: @Searle I saw that. It looks more like a perl problem than a regex one, here as the question seems to be *"How to coalesce `[]` into `[undef]`?"*

Comment: @sidyll: Maybe it is confusing. All i want is "[ number ]", if the showcatalog attribute is given and "[ undef ]" if it is not. However choroba's answer explains my misconception, but I still don't know if there is a regex solution.

Comment: @Searle yes there is a regex solution...I posted it. Can I change your question wording a little? I think the programmers here are not understanding it correctly.

Comment: @sidyll: Feel free!

Comment: @Searle thanks. Please refresh the page, it is here. About it returning undef if nothing matched, don't worry, it will happen automatically if there is no match anyway.

Comment: @sidyll: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that `?` is greedy, but it matches zero or one times until the condition is satisfied. Greedy is under this "zero or one" condition. In your case, since the whole regex is optional (surrounded by `?`), the "zero" times is given preference since it is the first possibility.

The engine goes step by step, trying to match your expression. In the first caracter of your string the zero match is already possible, so nothing is returned. In this sense, `?` is greedy if zero or one is possible (it will opt for one) but if the match already satisfied it is returned. Greedy does not take precedence over matching the whole expression or not. If refers to: if there is the possibility to take zero or one take one.

Your `[0-9]` is just `\d`. So if you need to extract the number you can use this:

```
/showcatalog=(\d+)/
```

To extract the whole text (`showcatalog` and numbers) just use

```
/(showcatalog=\d+)/
```

Similar to your command:

```
perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper([ "#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb" =~ /showcatalog=(\d+)/ ]);'
```

In a Perl script:

```
my $string1 = "#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb";
my ($number1) = $string1 =~ /showcatalog=(\d+)/;
print Dumper([ $number1 ]);

my $string2 = "#link text=blurb";
my ($number2) = $string2 =~ /showcatalog=(\d+)/;
print Dumper([ $number2 ]);
```

You can *force* a `undef` to appear anyway if you use something like:

```
/(?:.*showcatalog=(\d+))?/
```

Comment: `?:` isn't a look ahead

Comment: It's a non-capturing grouping

Comment: Sorry @Dada and thanks for noticing, I completely misread that

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Did you check the updated perl commands were giving the expected result ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret Yes

Comment: Well... so please write the complete perl commands and their output because on my system your regex isn't better than OP's one (the whole point and only difficulty being to get  `[undef]` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Updated

Comment: It still returns `[]` instead of `[undef]`.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I thought "greedy" automatically means "longest match", which seems to be wrong. I only use [0-9] on the command line so I don't have to think about how many backslashes to use in the current situation. And I didn't know about \K, thanks for that too. I still don't know how a regex has to look like to get [ undef ] instead of [], so I guess I'll have to make my query dumber and postprocess the query result.

Comment: @Searle Exactly, they are greedy when possible. The ultimate goal is still to match the expression, and this is done step by step. If in one of the steps `?` has two possibilities (zero or one) it will be greedy and choose one. But if only one possibility, that is the logical choice to attend the ultimate goal. Regarding it return a single element set to undef, that's a very interesting question and one that I do recommend you posting separately to the Perl section. Why `/(gibberish)?/` returns `(undef)` but `/(?=gibberish)/` returns `()`?

Comment: @Searle In a more real world usage though, in a script, you'd be saving the matched text in a variable similar to my updated code, right? In that case, you'd get what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @sidyll Good. Undownvoted, then (and more). I think this shouldn't be done, it's more a trick solving an XY problem than a proper parsing, but it looks like you answered the question now.

Comment: @DenysSéguret thanks, and yes, agreed. Indeed a bit XY, a lot of factors involved here and this back and forth editing to add details about multiple problems at once actually makes me tired :D sorry that I didn't catch what you meant earlier. I was paying more attention to the initial `?` greediness problem.

Comment: ¡Ay, caramba!, so simple. I didn't think of consequently putting the '.*' *inside* the paranthesis. This solves it, thanks! And now I'll lock myself into the study, practising asking questions propely...

Comment: @Searle LOL, we did a big round till reaching this, didn't we... :D Anyway, was we were saying this seems to be more a trick rather than a parsing "implementation". I don't know your inner details though. If it works for now, then all good :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're only getting the first match, where the `(?:...)?` group is empty thanks to the final `?`. It can match at any position in the string; to see all possible matches, use the `/g` modifier:

```
perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper([ "#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb" =~ /(?:showcatalog=([0-9]+))?/g ]);'
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          '123',
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

Comment: `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.` Just I want to know why I am getting this error while checking the above code `perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper([ "#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb" =~ /(?:showcatalog=([0-9]+))?/g ]);'` in windows 7 cmd

Comment: @ssr1012: In windows, you must use outer double quotes in the command line.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the behaviour, thanks for stopping me scratching my head. Do you know how to express a regex to achieve the expected outputs?

Comment: @Searle: Frankly, I don't understand what you want to achieve. What input is possible, what output is expected?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this pattern

```
 /.*showcatalog=([0-9]+)|/
```

The `.*` forces a backtrack to find `showcatalog=([0-9]+)` anywhere in the string, and the `|` also allows the null string to match (which it always will) if the first alternative fails, leaving `$1` set to `undef`

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper [ "#link showcatalog=123 text=blurb" =~ /.*showcatalog=([0-9]+)|/ ]'
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = [
          '123'
        ];
```

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper [ "#link xxx=123 text=blurb" =~ /.*showcatalog=([0-9]+)|/ ]'
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef
        ];
```

Comment: That's clever, thanks. I hope you're ok with me accepting sidyll's answer, as he posted his solution earlier...

Comment: @Searle: It's entirely up to you which one you choose, but I can't see any of sidyll's several answers that work. Which one did you pick?

Comment: The one with /(?:.*showcatalog=(\d+))?/ - the trick (for me) was adding the .* to the non capturing group.